# Why does this site assume C is best?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

From the FAQ :

"We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some C code in them,"

Why do 'the best' have to be in C ?.

What's wrong with assembler, or BASIC, or pseudo code ?

Comment: OMG, the FAQ does not list every possible programming language used on microcontrollers!

Comment: Because we don't have syntax highlighting for Basic, ASM, or pseudo-code ;)

Comment: @W5VO: We could really use syntax highlighting for Gibberish, since that seems to be a popular lanaguage here recently.

Comment: @OlinLathrop you know who will stop visiting at some point :)

Answer (score 10):

You are correct. It does not have to be C code, we just referenced by far the most common code we see on the site.

If you are explaining how you are coding something it will help. If you are debugging and having an issue with behavior your actual code would be better then psuedo code, as implementation is possibly the issue, but in other cases psuedo code probably saves quite a bit of space on the screen.

Answer (score 8):

This is splitting hairs beyond diminishing returns.

I've never seen a question down-voted or closed because the code snippet was in some language other than C.  Provided that everything else is valid.

Comment: Hair splitting ?. Take an analogy : "The best cars to drive have 4 wheels, comfortable seats, and are made by Ford."

Comment: @Buzby By your analogy, the FAQ should read something like "We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or use Atmel parts."

Answer (score 7):

You are correct.  C is not required and it is wrong of the FAQ to specifically say you should to post C code.  The FAQ should not be in the business of telling people what language to use or what is "best".  This should be fixed to say "source code".

Comment: C was used to be short and sweet and specify a code output, also due to its very high use in embedded, you think it is worth changing?

Comment: @Kortuk is it that much work then?

Comment: @CamilStaps It can be done easily, I personally, thought it was a good example of focused. I can change it if there is some agreement. Which this makes me thing there is.

Comment: @Kortuk: Yes, I think it's worth changing.  I really resent the message of *"assembly programmers need not apply"*, although it applies to all other languages that aren't C.

Comment: *Embedded code* instead of *C code*.

Comment: OlinLathrop, Good point. I did not mean it that way, and I dont think anyone did. I prefer source code to embedded code @kaz. If we think it worth it this could have a meta question.

Comment: Or `(C/C++/Assembly/Etc)` @Kortuk

Comment: Done. This has been changed to "source code" by @Kortuk

Comment: Was going to update it again if people asked about different options in meta, but I just took care of it.