# Assembly and Basic syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I request the feature of syntax highlighting Assembly and Basic code. As [W5VO said](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/why-does-this-site-assume-c-is-best#comment6163_2859), we don't have it yet. However, Assembly is used regularly on this site. And while we're at it, why not add Basic as well?

Both languages aren't included in the standard Google-Prettify package. However, there's an [extension for Basic](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#langs).

There isn't an Assembly extension yet, but perhaps it can be made by the team? It would make already obfuscated (because of *being* assembly) code better readable.

Comment: Assembly is very very system dependent though!

Comment: Assembly has a very simple syntax, compared to Basic and C. Although, highlighting things like jumps would be neat.

Comment: @Kortuk AFAIK the instructions are different for each system, but isn't the syntax the same? I once looked into TI ASM and it looked pretty much the same as PIC ASM. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @CamilStaps Yes, you are probably correct there, I was thinking of how different commands are and how hard highlighting would be, but if you did something simpler it would be very easy.

Comment: Beyond just the fact that different ISAs have different op-codes, there is a lot of variation between assembly languages: How to indicate hex/binary/octal numbers, how to indicate registers as operands, how to indicate different addressing modes, what kind of operations can be done to calculate operand addresses, how to indicate comments ... these things all change between different assembly languages.

Comment: A worthwhile syntax higlighter would need to understand at least some of that. Just highlighting the first token on the line (because that's the op-code) isn't really very useful.